# Angularjs:Constant value is not accessible in the app.config block

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple module where I have some constant values that get set at start up needed for the entire SPA. Here is a code snippet where I have defined some constant values. I am trying to access some of these values in the config block. I have them injected in my config block. But when I try to access them I get an undefined.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('coremodule', ['AdalAngular']);

    app.constant('CLIENT_ID', 'Test_Client_Id');
    app.constant('TENANT', 'Test_Tenant');

    app.config(
   ['$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider'
    function ($httpProvider, adalAuthenticationServiceProvider, CLIENT_ID,TENANT) {
        console.log(CLIENT_ID); //Client_ID is undefined
        adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init({
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
            tenant: TENANT
        }, $httpProvider);
    }
   ]);
})();
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add them as their string representation, add 'CLIENT_ID' and 'TENANT' after the other 2 and you should be good to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment before, you forgot to add the String representation of your constants.

Add 'CLIENT_ID' and 'TENANT' to the list and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing dependancy in you array annotation which are `'CLIENT_ID','TENANT',`

```
app.config(
   ['$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', 'CLIENT_ID','TENANT',
    function ($httpProvider, adalAuthenticationServiceProvider, CLIENT_ID,TENANT) {
       //..code here
    }
]);
```